# How to get reuse lines of code using SonarQube API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Is it possible to use the API to get sum of **reused lines of code**? Please advise.

Additional info:

1. Reused LOC = number of lines of code from initial baseline (before start of evolution on Project independent of later deletion of code)
2. Deleted LOC are not taken into account
3. Comments, test scripts, automated generated lines are excluded. Only source code for operational software is included

Regards,
Mircea

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make clear whether you're looking for code that has been copy/pasted.

Comment: Just added some additional information, i.e. definition of Reused LOC (lines of code). Not sure what you mean by "code that has been copy/pasted", this is irrelevant I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is `Lines of Code - New Lines of Code`, and API calls certainly exist to [get these values](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/measures).

Comment: Great, this is I think the answer we needed. Since we are still on ver. 4 we need to upgrade to the latest version. Thanks!